# Can i make a Game for play store on my own

Tags: game-design

I am not sure what i am asking for. Sorry if this question look stupid.

I love to play games on android and pc . Some times very cool  ideas strike me , but i don't know what to do with them. and they vanish over time.

I got no computer science background , since i am a math student . Although i learned C++ for a week for a exam. In short I know C++ but just the alphabets.

Is it possible that i can learn to make games. What should i have to learn.
Is it possible to learn from youtube. Since it's like side hobby i can give it few hours a day ( not money ).

Comment: What would make it impossible for you to learn to make games for the Play Store? Plenty of other folks have done it, so have faith in your abilities! Just dive in and give it a try: search for some existing tutorials, and work through the ones that look good to you. If you run into trouble along the way, you can ask here about solving a specific problem you encounter.

Comment: I suggest that you learn to use either unity or unreal engine. (unity might be easier). Also, if you want to get into it there is a lot of ten dollar courses (udemy.com is a good site to do this, unfortunately you can't download any of the videos) that you could buy that could get you making  video games pretty quickly. GameDev.tv has a lot of popular ten dollar courses.  Of course if you want to spend zero dollars, you could probably find a lot of youtube videos for unity and unreal that could get you started, maybe a full course.

Comment: BTW, if you want to try the udemy courses they might say they are 100$ or 20$ but if you just wait a while (like a week maybe) they will have a "sale" and everything will be from 10 to 12 dollars.

Comment: Thank you all of you for your advise .